# JTable error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 0

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I created a *JTable* in Java Swing.

How do I update it so that it displays all the values stored in my MySQL database?

I tried searching on the web, but still no luck.

This is my code...

```
    try{
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Users ");
        ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
        while(result.next()){
            salesTable.setValueAt(result.getString("users"), 1, 1);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle){
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I keep getting the `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 0` error.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could tell me where I am going wrong and a possible fix for this bug.

Comment: At what line are you getting the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Can you add the stacktrace?

Answer (score 4):

This method call
`result.getString(name)`
expects the name of a column, not the name of a table.

Probably that's where your confusion comes from.

You need to loop through all your column
names and call this method for each one.

Also, the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`
comes from the salesTable not from the ResultSet.

Review these two items and you should be able to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

```
salesTable.setValueAt(result.getString("users"), 1, 1);
```

I'm guessing you have an empty TableModel.

You can't just use the `setValueAt(...)` method to add data to a `TableModel`. The setValueAt(...) method is used to UPDATE existing data in the model. This means the row and column must already exist in the TableModel.

To add new data to the TableModel you need to use the `addRow(...)` method of the DefaultTableModel.

See the `Table From Database Example.java` code from [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/). It will give you and example of how to dynamically load a TableModel from a `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, where you would clean and fill your jTable, place this:

```
dtm.setRowCount(0);
```

Where `dtm` is your model in regards to jTable. What this does is clean your model prior each fill.